# Problema con peticiones POST dentro de un bucle FOR en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

estoy empezando en Angularjs y Javascript y estoy teniendo problema con las peticiones a un API REST.

Este es mi función:

```
 $scope.exportERP=function(){

      // En primer lugar insertamos los artículos.
      var artUrl = urlERP + "art_m" + apiKeyERP;
      var artUrlFiltro = artUrl + "&filter%5Bref%5D=";
      $scope.dataArt = $scope.art_m;

      // Recorremos los artículos del carrito
      for(i=0;i<$scope.carrito.length;i++){
      // Comprobamos si el artículo contiene accesorios y los insertarmos o actualizamos en la BBDD.
        if ($scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados.length > 0){
            //Recorremos uno a uno los accesorios
         for (j =0;j<$scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados.length;j++) {  

           $scope.dataArt.name = $scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados[j].descripcion.toUpperCase();
           $scope.dataArt.ref = $scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados[j].codigo;
           $scope.dataArt.pvp = Math.round($scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados[j].puntos * $scope.datosDistribuidor.coeficiente);

           $http.get(artUrlFiltro + $scope.dataArt.ref) //Petición con filtro por referencia del artículo. Nos permite saber si existe ya o no.
              .success(function(accesorio){  // Exíste el accesorio.

                if (accesorio.count == 0){ // No existe el artículo 

                  $http.post(artUrl, $scope.dataArt)
                  .success(function(data){
                    console.log("Accesorio insertado con éxito");
                    console.log(data);
                  })
                  .error(function(err){ // Error la actualizacion del accesorio.
                    console.log(err);
                  }); 

                } 

              }); 
         }
       } 
     }
 }
```

Pero dentro del último FOR (contiene dos valores) se ejecutan las dos peticiones GET seguidas y cuando se realiza el POST se envía siempre el último valor. ¿Por qué no se ejecutan secuencialmente para cada valor dentro del for? Espero que se me entienda y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que backend utilizas? Asp.Net Web Forms, Asp.Net Mvc o Php?

Comment: Hola Einer, uso NodeJS. Es una aplicación de escritorio.

Answer (score 2):

Tanto `$http.get` como `$http.post` son métodos asíncronos que devuelven [promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise), lo que quiere decir que muy probablemente los valores de `$scope.dataArt` no sean los que estas esperando en cada vuelta del `for` porque antes de que la primera petición `get` haya terminado y entre en el `.success()` ya se habrán hecho todas las iteraciones del `for`

**UPDATE**

Podrías utilizar las mismas promesas de los métodos `get` y `post` para esperar en cada vuelta,te he añadido algo de código.

```
$scope.exportERP=function(){

      // En primer lugar insertamos los artículos.
      var artUrl = urlERP + "art_m" + apiKeyERP;
      var artUrlFiltro = artUrl + "&filter%5Bref%5D=";
      $scope.dataArt = $scope.art_m;

      //----------INICIALIZAMOS LOS PROMISE A RESOLVE---------------//
      var getPromise=new Promise().resolve();
      var postPromise=new Promise().resolve();

      // Recorremos los artículos del carrito
      for(i=0;i<$scope.carrito.length;i++){
      // Comprobamos si el artículo contiene accesorios y los insertarmos o actualizamos en la BBDD.
        if ($scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados.length > 0){
            //Recorremos uno a uno los accesorios
         for (j =0;j<$scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados.length;j++) {  

          //----------ESPERAMOS HASTA EL RESOLVE DE CADA UNA DE LAS PETICIONES PARA EJECUTAR LA SIGUIENTE---------------//
           $.when(getDef,postDef).then(function(){
                $scope.dataArt.name = $scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados[j].descripcion.toUpperCase();
                $scope.dataArt.ref = $scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados[j].codigo;
                $scope.dataArt.pvp = Math.round($scope.carrito[i].accesoriosSeleccionados[j].puntos * $scope.datosDistribuidor.coeficiente);

              //----------REINICIALIZAMOS LA VARIABLE CON LA NUYEVA PROMESA---------------//
              getPromise=$http.get(artUrlFiltro + $scope.dataArt.ref); //Petición con filtro por referencia del artículo. Nos permite saber si existe ya o no.
              getPromise.success(function(accesorio){  // Exíste el accesorio.

                if (accesorio.count == 0){ // No existe el artículo 

                  //----------REINICIALIZAMOS LA VARIABLE CON LA NUYEVA PROMESA---------------//
                  postPromise=$http.post(artUrl, $scope.dataArt);
                  postPromise.success(function(data){
                    console.log("Accesorio insertado con éxito");
                    console.log(data);
                  })
                  .error(function(err){ // Error la actualizacion del accesorio.
                    console.log(err);
                  }); 

                } 

              }); 
           });

         }
       } 
     }
 }
```

Lo malo de esto, es que esta convirtiendo acciones asíncronas en acciones sincronas, y en Javascript esto no suele acabar muy bien. En la ejecución de este código, todo tu programa va a estar bloqueado hasta que no finalice esta acción.

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta, no dudes en marcarla como aceptada ;)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Hictus, sospechaba sobre los métodos asíncronos. ¿Cómo podría resolver esto? Con un factory?